# Python Flask - web app to NOT share variables between multiple users

Tags: html, python-3.x, web, flask, gunicorn

I have a Flask web app written in Python3. The issue I have though is, that all the variables are always shared between all users that access my website. 
For example, if user1 during his time on my website clicks a button which in Python3 does `var1 = "aaa"` and then populates this variable into an HTML input field, then all of the other users accessing the website will see the input field with value `aaa`.

I'm using gunicorn3 as my WSGI. I have also tried to `gunicorn3 python-docx:app -k gevent --worker-connections 1000` but that didn't help at all.
(python-docx is the name of my Python3 file)

How can I make sure, that the variables in my Python code are NOT shared between each sessions of different users? I want to make sure, that only the variables and their values are visible to each user specifically, not have them shared like now.

Is it possible?

Thank you very much.

Edit: I do not use database nor do I use a login system for my web app. My web app is public without any user management so anyone can use the web app's functionality for free.

Comment: are you using a database? rather than setting `foo = aaa` you can query for the users foo  in the database and populate with that.

Comment: I do not use database nor do I use a login system. My web app is public without any user management so anyone can use the web app's functionality.

Comment: You can have a look at using [sessions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sessions.htm) to create a unique session for each user on your site. there is a blog post about using session variables [here](https://hackingandslacking.com/managing-flask-session-variables-f4c5ccef54c0).
But this still comes down to needing a database to handle the different data between client sessions.

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is solved partially if you can identify Users(differentiate requests)

I know you are not using any authentication, so instead you can use timestamp when user requests the page capture the time stamp for that user in dictionary

Instead of using `var1="aaa"`
use: `dict['fixed_request_time_stamp']={var1:"aaa"}`

So when user request page, a unique time_stamp will created and sent to user along with page, that will submitted back to server when user submit form along with data("aaa") ("timestamp")